# Stripping namespace from a particular element in soap message

Tags: xslt

MY requirement is to get expected output from the input message using xslt .
The xslt which i am using has been provided for review..
Input message :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:v2="http://service..com/esbd/customer/customerlookup/v2"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:v1="http://schema..com/esbd//esbSubHeader/v1">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
    soapenv:mustUnderstand="0">
      <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username></wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">
        1</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
    **<base:TrackingInfo xmlns:base="http://base.canonical.something.com/">
       <ApplicationId>BMW</ApplicationId>
      <MessageID>112</MessageID>
      <CorrelationID>2356260273</CorrelationID>
    </base:TrackingInfo>**
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <web:lookUpCustomer xmlns:web="http://webservices.service.something.com/">
      <arg0>
        <BirthDttm />
      </arg0>
    </web:lookUpCustomer>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

expected output :
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:v1="http://schema.something.com/esbd/esbSubHeader/v1"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:v2="http://service.something.com/esbd/customer/customerlookup/v2">
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="0"
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>something</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">
        something1</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
    **<TrackingInfo>
      <ApplicationId >
      BMW</ApplicationId>
      <MessageID >
      112</MessageID>
      <CorrelationID >
      2356260273</CorrelationID>
    </TrackingInfo>**
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <web:lookUpCustomer xmlns:web="http://webservices.service.something.com/">
     <arg0>
        <BirthDttm />
      </arg0>
    </web:lookUpCustomer>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

i am trying to get the output using the below xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:base=""http://base.canonical.something.com/"" 
  xmlns:v2="http://service.something.com/esbd/owg/customer/customerlookup/v2"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:v1="http://schema.something.com/esbd/owg/esbSubHeader/v1"
exclude-result-prefixes="base v2 v1">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="base:*">
               <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(. = namespace-uri(..))]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

but instead of getting expected output getting below O/P message 

    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:v1="http://schema.something.com/esbd/esbSubHeader/v1"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:v2="http://service.something.com/esbd/customer/customerlookup/v2">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="0"
        xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>something</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">
            something1</wsse:Password>
          </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
        **<TrackingInfo>
          <ApplicationId xmlns:base="http://base.canonical.something.com/">
          BMW</ApplicationId>
          <MessageID xmlns:base="http://base.canonical.something.com/">
          112</MessageID>
          <CorrelationID xmlns:base="http://base.canonical.something.com/">
          2356260273</CorrelationID>
        </TrackingInfo>**
      </soapenv:Header>
      <soapenv:Body>
        <web:lookUpCustomer xmlns:web="http://webservices.service.something.com/">
         <arg0>
            <BirthDttm />
          </arg0>
        </web:lookUpCustomer>
      </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Could anybody please help me out where exactly i am going wrong ....

Comment: That is a typo. in the xslt you just replace "http://base.canonical.owg.walgreens.com/" with "http://base.canonical.something.com/" ..

Answer (score 0):

In your XML, the prefix `base` is bound to URI:

```
"http://base.canonical.something.com/"
```

Your stylesheet binds it to:

```
"http://base.canonical.owg.walgreens.com/"
```

For this reason, the template:

```
<xsl:template match="base:*">
```

matches nothing and the default identity transform template is applied to elements whose name starts with the `base` prefix.

Once you fix that, you should be getting the expected output. Note that the instruction:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(. = namespace-uri(..))]"/>
```

is unnecessary.

---

Note also that:

```
<ApplicationId xmlns:base="http://base.canonical.something.com/">BMW</ApplicationId>
```

is **exactly** the same thing as:

```
 <ApplicationId>BMW</ApplicationId>
```

If you are bothered about the redundant namespace declaration (which only *some* processors will copy from the original), add one more template to your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(namespace-uri())]">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

or extend the existing one to:

```
<xsl:template match="base:* | *[not(namespace-uri())]">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

But all of this is just cosmetics: the resulting XML is semantically the same as the one received without making these changes.

Comment: Working fine , Thanks ..One more doubt . if I want to  remove certain name spaces from soapenv:Envelope like xmlns:v1 and xmlns:v2 what i need to add in my code..

Comment: It is not easy in XSLT 1.0. Let me ask you something: do you really need to have prefixes in the output? IOW, can your target application accept `<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">` instead of the equivalent `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">`?

Comment: @user3347963 Is this question answered? If not, why not?